# How do I determine the version of my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

It doesn't make sense that I need a body for this question. How do I determine the version of my SQL Server?

Comment: the reason you need a body is to explain what you've tried so far, and what result that gave you. In this case, googling for sqlserver version showed me http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185  as the first result, and looking under "How to determine which version and edition of SQL Server Database Engine is running" on that page gave PHPDEV's first suggestion below. So did you try that? If not, what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

or

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY('edition')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the following query.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Execute the following when connected to the instance.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```